# Version mismatch for aclocal

Tags: linux, autotools, automake

I'm working in Kali Linux trying to build gnss-sdr from source (https://github.com/gnss-sdr/gnss-sdr) and I am getting the following make error.

```
/bin/bash: aclocal-1.14: command not found
Makefile:957: recipe for target '/root/gpspoof/gnss-sdr/thirdparty/glog/glog-0.3.4/aclocal.m4' failed
make[3]: *** [/root/gpspoof/gnss-sdr/thirdparty/glog/glog-0.3.4/aclocal.m4] Error 127
CMakeFiles/glog-0.3.4.dir/build.make:111: recipe for target 'glog-0.3.4/src/glog-0.3.4-stamp/glog-0.3.4-build' failed
make[2]: *** [glog-0.3.4/src/glog-0.3.4-stamp/glog-0.3.4-build] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/glog-0.3.4.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/glog-0.3.4.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
root@kali:~/gpspoof/gnss-sdr/build# aclocal
aclocal       aclocal-1.15
```

I have aclocal-1.15 installed, I'm under the impression I need to fix the aclocal.m4 file mentioned in the error message. I edited the version number of aclocal in that aclocal.m4 file, which gave me a different error about automake.

```
root@kali:~/gpspoof/gnss-sdr/build# make
[  1%] Performing build step for 'glog-0.3.4'
 cd /root/gpspoof/gnss-sdr/thirdparty/glog/glog-0.3.4 && automake-1.14 --gnu
/bin/bash: line 4: automake-1.14: command not found
Makefile:928: recipe for target '/root/gpspoof/gnss-sdr/thirdparty/glog/glog-0.3.4/Makefile.in' failed
make[3]: *** [/root/gpspoof/gnss-sdr/thirdparty/glog/glog-0.3.4/Makefile.in] Error 1
CMakeFiles/glog-0.3.4.dir/build.make:111: recipe for target 'glog-0.3.4/src/glog-0.3.4-stamp/glog-0.3.4-build' failed
make[2]: *** [glog-0.3.4/src/glog-0.3.4-stamp/glog-0.3.4-build] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/glog-0.3.4.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/glog-0.3.4.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And again the version of automake I have installed is 1.15.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to run aclocal, autoconf, automake, make --distclean in the directory mentioned in the error with the aclocal file.

Comment: This helped me deal with a similar problem: protobuf-3.6.1 + automake-1.15

It's just the make step that was different for me, I didn't have to use the `--distclean` flag